# Blazor form InputText binding to dictionary/dynamic?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

So I would like to be able to achieve something like the following:

```
<EditForm Model="@formItems" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <InputText id="name" @bind="formItems["Name"]" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public Dictionary<string, object> formItems = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "John Doe" }
    };

    private void HandleValidSubmit() {
        // Process form submit
    }
}
```

So instead of creating a specific object to hold the values instead use a Dictionary to do two-way binding to form items. Ideally would be able to use `dynamic` but I don't believe this is possible.

Is anything like above possible?

Comment: [Polite] You have an answer below from @hesolar that shows you how to get around your immediate problem, but your code suggests you are trying to built a dynamic form.  Dictionaries are great, but you lose strong typing which then leads to problems in defining Input controls, how do you solve validation, .... ,......  There's a reason why there's not a plethora of dynamic "WYSIWYG" form builders out there.  It's one of the Holy Grail's of coding.  Been there, done that, got the scars!  Bon voyage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but with a little trick:
I mean your option cant be done with two-way binding because you CANT change a dictionary key in c#(try in a compiler).
Try somthing like this (sorry but my vs is in spanish):
[image]
Key property is read only.

Check this.

```cs
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="@formItems" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    @foreach (var option in formItems)
    {
        <tr>
        <td><label>@option.Key</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs c) => changeKey(c.Value.ToString(),option.Key,option.Value))" value=@option.Key/></td>
    </tr>
    }


    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>


@code {

    public Dictionary<string, object> formItems = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "John Doe" },
        { "Other Name", "Johns father" }
    };
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Process form submit
    }
    public void changeKey(string newKey, string oldKey, object oldValue)
    {
        this.formItems.Remove(oldKey);
        this.formItems.Add(newKey, oldValue);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed and simplified version of the @hesolar idea:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@_formDict" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    @foreach (var option in _formDict)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><label>@option.Key</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" @onchange="@(c => _formDict[option.Key] = c.Value)" value=@option.Value /></td>
        </tr>
    }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    public Dictionary<string, object> _formDict = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Name", "John Doe" },
        { "Age", 30 }
    };

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Process form submit
    }
}
```